# Change trn news site?

Tags: newsreader

How can I change the news site (url) that the [*trn*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trn/) program uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in the access file. You can edit the system-wide settings in (probably) `/usr/local/lib/trn/access.def` or create a user-specific file in `~/.trn/access`. You have to add the news server, then put it in a group:

```
[gmane]
NNTP server = news.gmane.org
# Auth User =
# Auth Password =

[group 1]
ID = gmane
Newsrc = ~/.trn/newsrc-gmane
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make sure the `NNTPSERVER` environment variable is set to the hostname of the server you want to use (e.g. `news.gname.org`) prior to starting `trn`.